# Not able to receive accessToken and even not able to fire getLoginStatus Event?

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

Hi  i am new to facebook APP. I am working on Facebook C# SDK  and Javascript SDK. But the problem is i am not able to get the AccessToken and i am not able to debug the code. Please find the below code

```
<div id="fb-root"></div> <!-- This initializes the FB controls-->   
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',   // App ID
            status: true,               // check login status
            cookie: true,               // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true                 // parse XFBML             
        });

        // Additional initialization code here
        alert("Additional initialization code here");
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) 
        {
            debugger; ****//Debugger is not Raising****
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // connected
                alert("Connected");
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // not_authorized
            } else {
                // not_logged_in
            }
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.session) {
                // logged in and connected user, someone you know
                alert("Connected");
            } else {
                // no user session available, someone you dont know
            }
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
            alert("Additional initialization code here");
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                alert("Bhuvan");  `// Event Not Raising`
                // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                // request, and the time the access token 
                // and signed request each expire
                debugger;
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                // TODO: Handle the access token

                // Do a post to the server to finish the logon
                // This is a form post since we don't want to use AJAX
                var form = document.createElement("form");
                form.setAttribute("method", 'post');
                form.setAttribute("action", 'FacebookLogin.aspx');

                var field = document.createElement("input");
                field.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                field.setAttribute("name", 'accessToken');
                field.setAttribute("value", accessToken);
                form.appendChild(field);

                document.body.appendChild(form);
                form.submit();

            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                // but has not authenticated your app
            } else {
                // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
            }
        });

    };

        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function (d) {         
            var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
            ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
        } (document));



</script> 
    <div class="fb-login-button"  data-show-faces="true" data-width="400" data-max-rows="1"></div>
```

I am able to login but, i am not able to handle any Events.
May i know why i am not able to raise the events, and why i am not able to retreive the acccess code?

Comment: pls look in to firebug or crome console if any js errors are there and paste those here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Load the SDK Asynchronously by adding this code chunk above your script,ie 
above this line `window.fbAsyncInit = function () {`

Add this :

```
// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d) {
var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
} (document));
```

Also add channel file inside FB.init({});

```
channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/Beta/channel.html', // Path to your Channel File LIVE
```

create an html file called channel.html in the root folder
*file contents*

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No this is is not Working.. ? What should be my Channel File... I created an another ASPX page.. and i linked in Channel URl as  channelUrl: '//' + window.location.hostname + '/FaceBookIntegration/WebForm1.aspx', is it  right?

Comment: pls see the edit to the answer above for channel file contents

Comment: As per the Chrome Console, its showing me an error as "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains"

Comment: @Bhuvan Have you created an AppId or are you using appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' as such,Please create your AppId in facebook first if not done and replace 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' with it.ALSO in the facebook site put Site Domain as localhost for local site.

Comment: Yes , Ur Right.. i already created the APP Id. but i failed to set the Web site URL previously.. Now its working fine when i changed it to localhost.. Thank you